# How to query for today's date and 7 days before data?

Tags: sql

I'm using sql server 2008. How to query out a data which is the date is today and 7 days before today ?

Comment: Then why have you tagged with mysql?

Comment: Check this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Answer (score 44):

Try this way:

```
select * from tab
where DateCol between DateAdd(DD,-7,GETDATE() ) and GETDATE()
```

Comment: He wants only date, so it might be a good idea to replace SYSDATETIME() with GETDATE()

Comment: @makciook - both [`SYSDATETIME()` and `GETDATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) return datetime values.

Comment: @Damien - true, but SYSDATETIME() gives you unneeded precision, and the name is not appropriate for the use and future maintenance.

Comment: @makciook - So, you're from the school of "If someone's unfamiliar with T-SQL, and looks at this function, they might be more easily fooled into thinking it's only dealing with Dates when they see `GETDATE()`, even though it's still actually working with datetime values" and you think that this is a *good* thing?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, no I mean when you make a lot of scripts you can easily forget what you actually meant putting `SYSDATETIME()` instead of `GETDATE()` ;)

Answer (score 10):

Query in Parado's answer is correct, if you want to use MySql too instead GETDATE() you must use (because you've tagged this question with Sql server and Mysql):

```
select * from tab
where DateCol between adddate(now(),-7) and now()
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to refer to other answers on SO by their position (what I assume you meant by "upper query"), since votes can change the relative positions of answers. If you want to refer to another answer, it's usually best to add a link to it (each answer has a `share` option below it, from which a URL can be obtained) and/or to use the other users name.

Comment: Ok ok, sorry. I'm newbie ;)