# How to filter less than 7 days on my Query for my weekly report

Tags: sql, sql-server

this is my query

```
SELECT 
    StudentID, DateRegistered 
FROM 
    StudentTable 
WHERE 
    DateDiff(day, DateRegistered, '" & Date.Now & "') <= 7
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717515/how-to-query-for-todays-date-and-7-days-before-data) might help

Comment: Its Correct your query will work fine. but it will return all the previous records

Comment: yes, I want all the records that are under 7 days to appear

Comment: you are executing this At which environment

Answer (score 2):

You didn't tag you RDBMS, and every one has different functions for dates, but one of this should work fine:

```
SELECT StudentID, DateRegistered 
FROM StudentTable 
WHERE DateDiff(day, DateRegistered, now()) <= 7
```

Or

```
    WHERE DateDiff(day, DateRegistered, getdate()) <= 7
```

Or this:

```
CURDATE()
```

Note that I used the local DBMS to select the date, no need to do this with a paramether on the PHP side.

Comment: Although this comment is based on the SQL Server question tag, none of your your approaches will not use an index.  For a large table, this could be big deal.  It is best to use a `DATEADD()`  function to get the date 7 days ago, like: `WHERE DateRegistered>=DATEADD(day,7,GETDATE())`.  You must also be aware that `GETDATE()` returns time, so it is 7 days from the current date+time.  If you want to consider the entire day, look into "floor a datetime".  Use something like: `WHERE DateRegistered>=CONVERT(date,DATEADD(day,7,GETDATE()))` or any other way you want to floor the datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Date should be in "YYYY-MM-dd" format.

```
SELECT 
    StudentID, DateRegistered 
FROM 
    StudentTable 
WHERE 
    DateDiff(day, DateRegistered, '" & DateTime.Now.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') & "') <= 7
```

Comment: your query will not use an index and will table scan.  For small tables it won't make a difference, but as the table gets larger you will notice.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I added the formatted date to make sure datetime is in right format, op didn't say anything related to indexing or table size, so left it out.

Comment: I pointed out the index issue because it is simple mistake to make, and will really make a difference in query run time.  Every time you write a `WHERE` clause you should be thinking about how to hit an index.  If there is an index on `DateRegistered` it can't be used, because you put it through the `DATEDIFF()` function.  When you write it like: `WHERE DateRegistered>=DATEADD(day,7,GETDATE())` you use DateRegistered without changes, and an index can be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd = "SELECT StudentID, DateRegistered 
FROM StudentTable 
WHERE DateRegistered between @startdate and @enddate", connectionstring)

cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@StartDate",today.date.subtract(timespan.fromdays(7)))
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@EndDate",today)
```

Comment: This will use an index.  However I never prefer using `BETWEEN` it seems so ambiguous, will it use `>= and <=` or `> and <`.  I just use what is appropriate for the situation, and it is clear: `DateRegistered >= @startdate and DateRegistered<= @enddate` or `DateRegistered > @startdate and DateRegistered< @enddate`